# Prevent duplicate values being added from a text box to a list box

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox where a user scans a barcode then selects an 'add to list' button which adds them to a listbox. I'm trying to modify it to prevent duplicates being added but can't seem to find a way that works.

```
function addToList(barcode) {

    var barcode = document.getElementById("barcode").value.toUpperCase();
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
        document.getElementById("lstBox1").options.add(opt);            

        opt.text = barcode;
        opt.value = barcode;
        //$('barcode').val('');
        document.getElementById("barcode").value='';
    return false;
}
```

What would be the best way?

Comment: What is listbox? An array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to keep track of the values entered in an Array

Then by checking if the value exists in the array or not, you can add the value to the dropdown

---

```js
var allValues = [];
function addToList(){
    var barcodeInput = document.getElementById("barcode");
    var barcode = barcodeInput.value.toUpperCase();
    barcodeInput.value='';
    
    //if this value is already in the array, do nothing
    if( -1 !== allValues.indexOf(barcode) ){
        return;
    }
    
    allValues.push(barcode);
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    document.getElementById("lstBox1").options.add(opt);            
    opt.text = barcode;
    opt.value = barcode;
    
    return false;   
}
```

```css
select{
  min-width:100px;
}
```

```html
<input id="barcode" />
<br/>
<select id="lstBox1"></select>
<br/>
<button onclick="addToList()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value is not exist in the list before adding into the list.
You can try this

```
var listbox=document.getElementById("lstBox1")
for(var i; i<listbox.options.length; i++)
{
    if(listbox.options[i].value!=barcode)
    {
       var opt = document.createElement("option");
       opt.text = barcode;
       opt.value = barcode;
       listbox.options.add(opt); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether inputted value already exist in the optionlist. If not present then add the value, else do nothing.

```js
let found;

const submitBtn = document.querySelector('button');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const val = document.querySelector('input').value.toLowerCase();

    if(val.length > 0) {
        const optionsArr  = document.querySelectorAll('select > option');
        found = [...optionsArr].filter((option) => option.value.toLowerCase() === val);
        if(found.length == 0) {
            addToList(val);
        }
    }
});

function addToList(val) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = val;
    option.textContent = val;
    document.querySelector('select').appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Add</button>

<select name="" id="">
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example you can use keeping some of the elements in memory and using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as validation strategy. Also you can seen for the filter I am showing an example of [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to filter the duplicates.

```js
let list = document.getElementById('lstBox1');
let input = document.getElementById('barcode');
let button = document.getElementById('addOption');

function addToList() {
  let currentOptions = Array.from(list.options);
  let barcode = input.value.toUpperCase();
  let filter = currentOptions.filter(option => option.value == barcode);

  if (filter.length == 0) {
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = barcode;
    opt.value = barcode;
    list.options.add(opt);            
    input.value = '';  
  } else {
    alert('The value is duplicated');
  }
};

button.addEventListener('click', addToList);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="barcode">
<select name="" id="lstBox1">
  <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
</select>
<button id="addOption">Add Option</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is kind of bruteforce method but it will work. Using jQuery it
>   will be much simple.

1.This function will get all the list text

```
    function getOptTxt() {
        var x = document.getElementById("lstBox1").options.length;
        var txt = [];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        txt[i] += x.options[i].text;
        }
    }
```

2. You can check the barcode value ,If it is present in txt array or not if the value is not present in txt array then u can actually add the new option element

```
    var flag =0
     for (x in txt){
      if(barcode == x.toUpperCase()){
        flag =1
        break;
       }
     }
    if(flag == 0){
      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      document.getElementById("lstBox1").options.add(opt);
     }
```